making executable file with shc command on arm64 to be compatible with x86_64
i'm trying to send a bash script file using ssh to my remote server but first i want to make it executable on my own machine which is arm64 and then send the .exe file to remote server but remote server arch is x86_64, how can i use the 'shc' command to produce a .exe file to be compatible with x86_64?
on my own machine
shc -f test.sh -o test 

but on my ubuntu x86_64 can't execute it because it was compiled on a arm64 machine.
is there any way to make it work on arm64 with shc?

I would do without shc and let the script execute bash on the target system.

@cyrus yes but i don't want to reveal my source code, although i have license from the company to execute these .exe files but i can't make .exe for every archs.

i can't make .exe for every archs why not?

I just installed shc to see if I could solve your problem, but I wasn't able to get it to compile for a different architecture.  I tried to compile the script for i386 with gcc -march=i386 foo.x.c but it complained that i386 didn't support the x86_64 commands used.  Normally I cross compile from a ./configure script like this:
./configure                     \
   --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu    \
   --host=i386-pc-linux-gnu     \
   --target=i386-pc-linux-gnu   \
&& make -j 8                    \
&& make install

I'm not very familiar with using gcc directly to cross-compile for another architecture, maybe someone else more familiar with cross-compiling can suggest how to use gcc to compile for a different architecture.
I can see on my Ubuntu that there's a lot of packages for cross-compiler tools, such as alternate gcc versions just for cross-compiling on various architectures including ARM64, but I don't know how to use them.
I can see from the shc man page that it uses these environment variables:
CC      : C compiler command [cc]
CFLAGS  : C compiler flags   [none]
LDFLAGS : Linker flags       [none]

But I am not familiar with what would be put into these.
As an alternate workaround, rather than getting shc to compile the script for another architecture, you could run shc on that other architecture directly:
For example, you could use an ssh command to connect to the destination computer, compile it there, then scp the resulting file back to your end.
Another method would be to emulate the architecture locally using QEMU or another emulator that supports the architecture.  If you wanted to try that method, here's a guide:

Creating an arm64(aarch64) development environment with QEMU

